# oData get the body of a request using Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext

Tags: c#, odata

I generated an oData context using the VS oData client.
I can read data with no problem. using expressions like:
var container = new DefaultContainer(new Uri(url));
foreach(var customer in container.Customers)

The problem I have is by saving the data back. I cannot figure out why it is failing. I presume that there is an error in the request being sent but I cannot figure out how to get the actual request body.

I tried using one of the hooks in container.Configurations.RequestPipeline and also one of the events of DataServiceContext like SendingRequest2 or BuildingRequest but I still cannot figure out how to put all the pieces together.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks,
Ignacio

Comment: Try a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.

Comment: Was trying to avoid that :(
Seems weird that you can examine/change EVERYTHING except the actual body

Comment: The body is in the data section, it is not part of the headers.